# Number of socket connections in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I'm reading the book Mastering Apache Cassandra published in 2015. In this book, the author says each node of Cassandra opens two sockets per node.

I want to know what is the use case for each of these connections and if in the newer versions of Cassandra the number of connections has changed?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the program and how it connects, from what I have seen using DSE (5.1-6.7) is that each "connection" can open a single socket to each node, and one of the nodes will have an additional connection/socket (the coordinator). I have been able to validate this with netstat (netstat -nap | grep 9042). I know the threads provide high availability in case a node becomes unavailable. I believe that is all they are used for. I don't believe they are used to satisfy consistency requests as consistency requests don't fail if the application only connects to a single node. As these are threads in the JVM, it's hard to tell if they do other functions that I haven't experienced yet.

Again, this all depends on how the "program" establishes the connection though. cqlsh for example, only creates a single socket onto the host you provide (or the local host if you provide nothing). If that node goes down, so does your cqlsh session.

Anyone else seen anything different?

-Jim